# flashdata not working after deleting a record in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Good day all. I'm new to CodeIgniter and I'm trying to use flashdata for showing a "successful" message after deleting a record. I'm using jQuery to show my data.

Here is the code of `Model` page:

```
function delete_post($postID)
{
    $this->db->where('post_id', $postID);
    $this->db->delete('khanposts');
}
```

Code of `Controller` page:

```
function deletepost($postID)
{
    $this->khanpost->delete_post($postID);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Record Deleted!');
    redirect(base_url().'khanposts/index/');
}
```

Code of `View` page:

```
foreach ($posts as $row){
echo '<tr><td><a href="' .base_url(). 'khanposts/deletepost/' .$row['post_id']. '"><i>Delete</i></a></td></tr>';
}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.delmsg').hide();
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg')){ ?>
$('.delmsg').html('<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>').show();
});
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

Record gets deleted but I don't see any message after deleted. Am I doing wrong? Any solution will be helpful. Tnx.

Comment: When you view the page source, can you see the error message?

Comment: @Craig, no i don't see any message. But the record is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

First, but probably won't make a difference, but, i've reversed the 2nd to last and 3rd to last lines in your view code:

```
foreach ($posts as $row){
    echo '<tr><td><a href="' .base_url(). 'khanposts/deletepost/' .$row['post_id']. '"><i>Delete</i></a></td></tr>';
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.delmsg').hide();
        <?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg')){ ?>
            $('.delmsg').html('<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>').show();
        <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```

It appears to be an issue with the loading of the session library, I would guess.  So, check you have the session class loading either in the application/config/autoload.php config file by adding 'session' to the $autoload['libraries'] array : `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` ... or by using `$this->load->library('session')` in your controller.

If it's still not working, make sure you're in "development mode" in the root index.php file and that your development case looks like this:

```
    case 'development':
         error_reporting(E_ALL);
         ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

... and see if PHP can give you any additional information about what's going on.

Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can display the error message using php instead of Jquery. You can use like this

```
if($this->session->flashdata('msg'))
{?>
  <div class="delmsg"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata("msg"); ?></div>

<?php }
```